# Visual Studio Code - SQL Results Column Width

Tags: sql, visual-studio-code

I like using Visual Studio Code to query my SQL Databases, find it quicker and easier.

Anyhow, does anyone know how to automatically set the column widths to Autosize in the results window? It makes it tricky to work with due to the column width being narrow and not having an immediate way to resize all columns.

See below:

[SQL results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJvjk.png)

If there isn't a solution, i'll likely need to return to completing daily work in SMSS.

Thanks!

Comment: If I'm assuming the correct feature, this [appears to be a feature asked by many](https://github.com/Microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/172) but apparently not yet completed. Filed as **an enhancement**. Many others have mentioned switching back to SMSS as well within that link.

Comment: @PaulT. looks like you're right, back to SMSS it is!